# MongoDB validation fails

Tags: mongodb

I've used the validation rules for MongoDB, but validation fail on every insert.

```
db.createCollection("mycollection",{
validator:{
    $and:[ 
        {name: {$type:"string"}}, 
        {age: {$type:"int"}}   
    ]
}})
```

When add an entry

```
db.mycollection.insertOne({name:"Joseph", age: 18})
```

But I obtain always an error, with a generic message "Document failed validation".
Any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In mongodb the default type for int is Double.
So, you can set type Double in validation rule or try

```
db.mycollection.insertOne({name:"Joseph", age: NumberInt(18)}))
```

Comment: Thank you! This MongoDB decision makes no sense because `Number.isInteger(18)` is `true`.